# In VS2017, build doesn’t fail even when there is compile time errors

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, visual-studio-2017

I am using ssdt project (using VS2017 version - 15.1,  SSDT version - 15.1.61702.140). I have a stored proc with compile time error but when I build,  the build completes successfully.

Is there some project/vs setting that could be causing this behavior? Isn't this kind of scary?

**Product table:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Name] VARCHAR(50) NULL
)
```

**Stored proc:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspProductSelect]
    @name VARCHAR(50) = ''
AS
    SELECT * FROM Product as p where p.Name = @name;

    use Database1_3; -- this causes compile time issue;
```

and Visual Studio tells me there is an issue in the error window:

```
SQL80001: a USE database statement is not allowed in a procedure, function or trigger.
```

But if I build the project, it completes successfully! This cannot be the right behavior.
[image]

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this issue?

Comment: No. I reached out to the twitter handle of SSDT team, and they responded asking to log a defect. I didn't do that. I don't remember how I got around this.